# jquery Find greatest TD in a table

Tags: jquery

I have a table that looks similar to the following

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>Data here</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>Data here</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>Data here</td></tr>
</table>
```

How do I use jquery to retrieve the number 3 since it is the highest of the 3 rows?  I cannot use last or first since it is not guaranteed that the rows will be ordered.

Comment: Write a function to iterate through all first children of tr's and determine the largest one. Return the largest value.

Comment: 19 questions and one accepted answer??

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this:

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, $('td:first-child').map(function(i,elem){ 
    return Number($(elem).text()); 
}));
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FLwfP/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var max = 0;
$('#mytable tr').find('td:first').each(function(){
    max = Math.max($(this).html(),max);
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
    alert(max);
```

[code in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JY77G/)

Answer (score 0):

I guess jQuery can't do it streight, but you can do it your own.

```
var max = -1;
$("tr > td").each(function(index, element) {
    var n = Number($(element).html());
    if (n != NaN && max < n) {
        max = n;
    }
});

//console.log("your max value is " + max);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N6MaJ/

Answer (score 0):

You can read them into an array then use JavaScript's max function:

```
Math.max.apply(Math,$('#mytable td:nth-child(1)').map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
}).get());
```